# Load image button, jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have never used jquery before, so i might just have forgotten something.
what i want to do is add a button on my page that loads some images when pressed. or even make it load a div that i have created already.

In my head tag i have this.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("button").click(function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
  });
</script>
```

and in my body i have the button.

```
<button data-rel="img/inasecond.jpg">Click Me</button>
```

please help my out here, im going to study a little jquery later when i got the time, but right now i just need to learn how to use code found on the web.

Comment: wrap your code inside [`$(document).ready(){ //your code here });`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Add you <script> code after whole HTML completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. All you need to do is wrap it in `$(document).ready()`

So it should look like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
  });
});
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k5bL7pkj/3/)

Comment: Thanks i got it to work after looking at your demo ;) thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery cant run before the document is fully loaded. Hence:

Wrap your jQuery code inside

```
$(document).ready(){ //your jQuery here });
```

Then it should work ;)

Comment: i got it to work ;) what if i want it to load a div ? :)

Comment: then you put your div inside html("your div html inside here").

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(){ 
 $("button").click(function () {
    var imgUrl = $(this).data('rel');
    $("#area").html("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='description' />");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding script is easy in html, but look before what those scripts uses, if your script uses any dom elements then that script block should execute after that dom element.
like if you write an click event handler before body and button is in body then the handler will not attach to that button. In jQuery there is $(document).ready() method which takes a callback function which will get executed when your document gets loaded.

so here you have two options one is to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Your code here
})
```

or another option is move your script block at the end of body tag so when your script block will get executed, till all dom elements will already loaded